# Can you charge Bosch 18V batteries from your car?

Tags: drill, battery

I'm trying to find out if Bosch or someone else makes a charger for their 18V cordless tools that can charge from the cigarette lighter (actually from a solar panel that has a 12V cigarette lighter adapter). So far my searches have been unsuccessful, does anyone here know if there's something out there other than using their 120V charger with a power inverter that can do the trick?

Comment: Not sure if this is on topic here.

Comment: Not really. OK in chat, likely to get closed as off-topic in the Q&A section - too ephemeral, product and service recommnedations OT, etc. Given DC-DC converters, someone probably does make such a thing, but given the world of "all cordless batteries must be incompatible so we can sell more useless junk" I don't know about one for your specific model. 5 seconds with google does turn up "DEWALT DC9310 7.2-Volt-18-Volt 1-Hour Charger" for about $66 at amazon (or more, and possible less, but you get to do the shopping around.) But you have a bosch.

Comment: Have you considered cost.  My 18v Ryobi charger draws less than 80 watts. Harbor Freight sell units for $20. Likely cheaper than a name brand 12v to 18v charger.

Comment: @mikes I'm guessing you didn't read the whole question...

Comment: My comment was just to inform the OP that there are inverters large enough to power the charger at a reasonable cost.

Comment: @mikes Cost isn't the issue, converting 12v DC into 120v AC back to 12v DC  again is the issue. In my case I'm pretty certain a power inverter wouldn't work at all plugged into the adapter for my solar charger.

Answer (score 2):

[image]
Here's a/the bosch version - no idea if it fits your particular version of bosch 18V battery, which come in many incompatible versions, but it's the only one I can find.

Just making an "answer" to get the picture in...

Comment: Ya I eventually found that one, but it's for their older batteries. Doesn't look like bosch has one for their newer batteries.